# Nginx configuration for Magento running in subfolder

Tags: magento, nginx

I want to install additional copy of Magento to subfolder. It should work with URL rewrites. Please, tel me what changes I should do in default config (could be found here also - http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name DOMAIN.com;
    rewrite / $scheme://www.$host$request_uri permanent; ## Forcibly prepend a www
}

server {
    listen 80 default;
## SSL directives might go here
    server_name www.DOMAIN.com *.DOMAIN.com; ## Domain is here twice so server_name_in_redirect will favour the www
    root /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN.com;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex            on;
    }

    location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    }
}
```

Comment: will your other installation have a different domain? Or just /directory/ added to the main domain?

Comment: just /directory/ added to the main domain

Comment: Configuring this is going to be a headache. Could you explain why you want this?

Comment: I have Magento installed in my root folder (/var/www). I want to setup dev store in root/subcategory.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a solution that's mostly working, outlined in more detail here:

[Magento stores in subfolders using nginx proxy_pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406134/magento-stores-in-subfolders-using-nginx-proxy-pass)

I use proxy_pass to rewrite the URL and send it to a separate Nginx server directive based on the URL subdirectory. The second server directive sets the store code, and Magento handles the rest. I'm not sure it's the *most* elegant solution, but it works.

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    server_name www.DOMAIN.com *.DOMAIN.com;
    root /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN.com;

    ## Serve static files from the server on 80
    location ^~ /media/ {}
    location ^~ /skin/ {}                                                      
    location ^~ /js/ {}                                                       
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|swf|fla)$ {                      
        expires 1y;                                                             
        log_not_found off;                                                      
    } 


    location /STORE_CODE {
        rewrite           ^/STORE_CODE/(.*) /$1 break;                               
        proxy_pass        http://localhost:82;                                  
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass        http://localhost:81;                                  
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Then create server directives for port 81 and 82 using your existing configs like so:

```
server {
    listen localhost:81 default; # Make sure you change the port here!
... # Same configuration otherwise
}

server {
    listen localhost:82 default; # Make sure you change the port here!
... # Same configuration, except for:

    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE store_code; ## CHANGE THIS TO YOUR STORE CODE!
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
}
```

You'll want to set the base_url of your second store to `http://www.DOMAIN.com/STORE_CODE/`. Magento should take care of the rest.

Hope this helps!